# How do I address an issue with an overly wide index?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, non-clustered-index

I am not very proficient at SQL yet. I'm learning, but it's a slow process. I am working on a project at work which stores a good deal of information in a database in SQL Server. In one of the tables, ContactInformation, we're experiencing an error when an attempt to modify an entry runs afoul because a nonclustered index composed of all of the address information [exceeds 900 bytes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx). I've used `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` to verify that modifying an entry in the table leads to 3 `user_seeks` and 1 `user_update`.

The C# code does not seem to be directly calling the index. It executes a single `DbCommand` that consists of a stored procedure command of the `Update` variety with 19 parameters. My thoughts are to either eliminate the index or to try to break up the `DbCommand` into multiple updates with a smaller number of parameters in hopes of having a smaller index to work with.

I am a bit at sea due to my lack of experience. I welcome any advice on which way to turn next.

The Index consists of the following:

```
| Name                 | Data Type     | Size |
|----------------------|---------------|------|
| ContactInformationID | int           | 4    |
| CompanyID            | smallint      | 2    |
| Address1             | nvarchar(420) | 840  |
| Address2             | nvarchar(420) | 840  |
| City                 | nvarchar(420) | 840  |
| State                | nvarchar(220) | 440  |
| PostalCode           | nvarchar(120) | 240  |
| Country              | nvarchar(220) | 440  |
```

Yes, most of the columns are oversized. We apparently inherited this database from a different project. Our software limits most of the columns to no more than 100 characters, although there are some outliers.

Comment: What are the SQL data types and lengths of the columns which make up the index?

Comment: Can you normalize the table more? If you can, you can index on the foreign keys (typically `int`s), which would make the index a lot smaller.

Comment: SQL server will let you use index hints to try to force it to use that index...have you gone down that path?

Comment: @Twelfth
I was unaware of those. Some of the information about them suggests that they're dangerous for the uninitiated to use.

Comment: Why does all of this information have to be an index key? Does the app really seek on columns such ass Address1 and Address2 (considering that they might be null as well)? If not (likely) make them included columns.

Comment: The error seems clear enough. Why do you have an index with all of the address information? It's probably not very useful as an index. If it is to enforce uniqueness then you could use a trigger instead.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - It is better to let the query planner determine it in most cases...but it's not always correct. It's possible that it's already considered the index and choosing not to use it anyway. table with (index(myindex)) in the from clause is the syntax for it. remember indexs usually increase time of inserts because the index needs to be updated when new values are inserted...update is effectively an insert/delete...possible the update is causing the clustered index to need updating and thus slowing you down (index having the opposite effect you intend).  COnsider usr's comment as well

Comment: Can you post the DDL for the index. Go into object browser in SQL Management Studio, right click on the index and select `Script Index as Create to Clipboard` then paste it in here. If you drop (delete) that index now, you will be able to update. Since the index is too large it probably can't use it anyway so dropping it will not be a problem. Indexes speed up reads, and can also speed up updates. So take note of how fast the reads perform before and after you drop the index.

Answer (score 1):

The index size limit only applies to the key columns. It applies to all B-Tree bases storage modes (NCI and CI). This limit exists to ensure a certain degree on tree fanout in order to bound the tree height.

If you don't need to seek on columns such as Address1 and Address2 (considering that they might be null as well) make those columns included columns.

The index key should never be longer than the shortest key prefix that results in a unique index. Every column after that never helps compared to that column being included.

Answer (score 0):

If ContactInformationID is unique, which I have a feeling it very well could be, then having any other fields in the index is pointless.

Such an index is useful only for queries where the value of ContactInformationID is present as a query parameter, and when it is, the rest of the fields are immaterial.